# How to send a request and get a response using system.io.pipes

Tags: named-pipes

I'm trying to write a client and server that communicate through named pipes.  I need the the client to be able to send a query to the server and have the server send a response.  All of the samples on the web for System.IO.pipes either send a single string to the client or a single string to the server. I have found some examples of how to do that with the old Win32 pipes.  But, I can't use that.

Here is what I have so far.  I know it is a lot of code.  But, I think the issue may just be in one of the constructors for the pipe streams.

Client Code

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSend.Click
    Dim strMsg As String = ""
    Dim strRequest As String = "Send Key"
    Dim strErrMsg As String = ""

    PrintText("Creating new pipe client")
    'pipeStream = New NamedPipeClientStream(strPipeName)
    'pipeStream = New NamedPipeClientStream(strPipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None)
    pipeStream = New NamedPipeClientStream(strServerName, strPipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None, Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.None)

    PrintText("Connecting to server")
    pipeStream.Connect()
    pipeStream.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message

    PrintText("Sending request")
    'Send Request
    If SendPipeMessage(pipeStream, strRequest, strErrMsg) Then
    Else
        PrintText(strErrMsg)
    End If

    PrintText("Receiving response")
    'Process Response
    If ReadPipeMessage(pipeStream, strMsg, strErrMsg) Then
        PrintText(strMsg)
    Else
        PrintText(strErrMsg)
    End If

    pipeStream.Dispose()
    pipeStream = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function SendPipeMessage(ByRef pipeStream As NamedPipeClientStream, ByVal strMsg As String, ByRef strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnRetVal As Boolean = True
    Dim bytMessage() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim encoding As UTF8Encoding = Nothing

    Try
        encoding = New UTF8Encoding
        bytMessage = encoding.GetBytes(strMsg)
        pipeStream.Write(bytMessage, 0, bytMessage.Length)

    Catch ex As Exception
        blnRetVal = False
        strErrMsg = ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return blnRetVal
End Function


Private Function ReadPipeMessage(ByRef pipeStream As NamedPipeClientStream, ByRef strPipeText As String, ByRef strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnRetVal As Boolean = True
    Dim strTextChunck As String = ""
    Dim intNumBytes As Integer = 0
    Dim intNumChars As Integer = 0
    Dim bytMessage(10) As Byte
    Dim chars(10) As Char
    Dim decoder As Decoder = Nothing

    Try
        decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder
        strPipeText = ""
        Do
            strTextChunck = ""
            Do
                intNumBytes = pipeStream.Read(bytMessage, 0, bytMessage.Length)
                intNumChars = decoder.GetChars(bytMessage, 0, intNumBytes, chars, 0)
                strTextChunck = strTextChunck & New String(chars, 0, intNumChars)
            Loop While Not pipeStream.IsMessageComplete
            strPipeText = strPipeText & strTextChunck
        Loop While intNumBytes <> 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        blnRetVal = False
        strErrMsg = ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return blnRetVal
End Function
```

Server Code

```
Private Sub cmdListen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdListen.Click
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    Dim strRequest As String = ""

    Dim strErrMsg As String = ""

    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Create new pipe server stream")
    pipeStream = New NamedPipeServerStream(strPipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None)

    'Wait for connection
    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Listening for connection")
    pipeStream.WaitForConnection()

    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Receiving request")
    'Receive Request
    If ReadPipeMessage(pipeStream, strRequest, strErrMsg) Then
        bw.ReportProgress(0, "Request : " & strRequest)
    Else
        bw.ReportProgress(0, strErrMsg)
    End If

    'Get response
    strResponse = GetResponse(strRequest)

    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Sending response")
    'Send Response
    If SendPipeMessage(pipeStream, strResponse, strErrMsg) Then
        bw.ReportProgress(0, "Sent response")
    Else
        bw.ReportProgress(0, strErrMsg)
    End If
    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Done!")

    pipeStream.Disconnect()
    pipeStream.Dispose()
    pipeStream = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
    PrintText(e.UserState)
End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    PrintText(e.Result)
End Sub


Private Function SendPipeMessage(ByRef pipeStream As NamedPipeServerStream, ByVal strMsg As String, ByRef strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnRetVal As Boolean = True
    Dim bytMessage() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim encoding As UTF8Encoding = Nothing

    Try
        encoding = New UTF8Encoding
        bytMessage = encoding.GetBytes(strMsg)
        pipeStream.Write(bytMessage, 0, bytMessage.Length)

    Catch ex As Exception
        blnRetVal = False
        strErrMsg = ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return blnRetVal
End Function

Private Function ReadPipeMessage(ByRef pipeStream As NamedPipeServerStream, ByRef strPipeText As String, ByRef strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnRetVal As Boolean = True
    Dim strTextChunck As String = ""
    Dim intNumBytes As Integer = 0
    Dim intNumChars As Integer = 0
    Dim bytMessage(10) As Byte
    Dim chars(10) As Char
    Dim decoder As Decoder = Nothing

    Try
        decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder
        strPipeText = ""
        Do
            strTextChunck = ""
            Do
                intNumBytes = pipeStream.Read(bytMessage, 0, bytMessage.Length)
                intNumChars = decoder.GetChars(bytMessage, 0, intNumBytes, chars, 0)
                strTextChunck = strTextChunck & New String(chars, 0, intNumChars)
            Loop While Not pipeStream.IsMessageComplete
            strPipeText = strPipeText & strTextChunck
        Loop While intNumBytes <> 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        blnRetVal = False
        strErrMsg = ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return blnRetVal
End Function
```

When I start the client, it hangs on ReadPipMessage() and the server hangs on ReceivingRequest().  If I kill the client, the server reads in the request sent by the client.  But, it bombs on sending the response because the client is no longer running.

Is it not possible for the server to send and receive a message in the same connection?  I thought that was what PipeDirection.InOut meant.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, I am in same situation. Could you find the solution ? Once I read the request from client using ReadToEnd, the server pipe closes (and hence client side also closes.) Now how do i send the response to client?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the named pipes binding for WCF.  There are many good examples of how to use it available out there, for instance: http://www.jmedved.com/2010/03/named-pipes-in-wcf/